# screen scraping from TN3270 using Microsoft Host Integration Server 2013 / 2016 and ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are trying to develop a new web application for screen scraping from TN3270. We are using visual studio 2015 and HIS 2016.

Following code is written to connect TN3270

```
        var display = new SessionDisplay();
        var connection = new SessionConnectionDisplay();
        connection.DeviceType = TNDeviceType.IBM3278Model2;
        connection.Transport = SessionDisplayTransport.TN3270;
        connection.TN3270Port = 23;
        connection.TN3270Server = "server name";
        connection.HostCodePage = 37;
        display.Connect(connection);
```

The code is working fine when we execute it from console or windows application. But when we try to call from web application, I'm getting the following error:

> **An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.HostIntegration.SNA.Session.dll but was not handled in user code**
>
> Additional information: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

StackTrace

> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
> errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
> at Microsoft.HostIntegration.SNA.Session.SessionConnectionDisplay.CreateSessionConnection()
> at
> Microsoft.HostIntegration.SNA.Session.SessionConnectionDisplay.ConnectToSessionDisplay(SessionDisplay
> connectedSession)
> at Microsoft.HostIntegration.SNA.Session.SessionDisplay.Connect(SessionConnectionDisplay
> connection)

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Is the web application running In Visual Studio, or on IIS?

Comment: Visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connection.Implementation = ImplementationDetail.ManagedTn;

setting this property solved my problem.